# Adding current alarms to Start Menu

Tags: windows-10

Hey I was wondering if there was a way to put the windows 10 Alarms & Clock app on the Start Menu. I figured out how to add the app there and have set the icon to its largest but it just shows a grey square with a small bell icon in the bottom right. I only have three alarms that repeat weekly and it would just be nice to quickly open start and look to remind myself of them. (Whilst resizing it i realised that if I make it a medium icon it shows the next alarm in an animation, but not all three and if I change to size to anything else it sometimes breaks and just goes grey, or it just makes it act like Live Tile is turned off so just shows the alarm logo).

Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask but, any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you wish for is not part of the included "Alarms & Clock" app and "live tile". I think your best bet is to browse the Microsoft [App] Store for alternatives.

Your question inspired me to download "EasyNotes for Keep" which promises integration with my Google Keep notes. This app did not do the trick, so that's one down... more to try. Most others cost a dollar. I'm gonna keep the app I downloaded because it behaves like Google Keep does in the browser except can be accessed when I'm offline. It does not however take advantage of "Live Tile" functionality.

The reason I gravitated to Google Keep is because it enables one to set reminders just as well as any alarm but with notes, if that kind of thing is useful to you. I'd consider 'Google Keep' to be a "easier" than using a Calendar to set reminders but a little more advanced than a plain alarm app.

I think a "Live Tile" enabled app which integrates with Google Keep would combine quite nicely.